# express project not connecting to database (express)

Tags: sql-server, express

At work I have been creating a full stack website using express and react with a sql server database. 
I have now been self isolated due to the corona virus (everything at work was working fine).

I have restored the database and the code. 
I have enabled tc/ip and pipelines in sql server configuration manager.
I have the made sure the password for the sa account is correct.

this is what i receive

```
] Err:  ConnectionError: Connection is closed.
```

What else is there to check to make sure this is working? 
Any help in what I may have overlooked would be great

edit ----

using npm mssql here is config

```
var config = {
  user: "sa",
  password: "Mypassword123",
  server: "localhost", // You can use 'localhost\\instance' to connect to named instance
  database: "CDA"

  //enableArithAbort: false
};
```

[image]

Comment: Pls provide more info like, What database you're using, what database driver you're using? Maybe a sample of file where you're trying to connect with db could help.

Comment: updated check question :)

Comment: Can you connect to the db using SSMS or any other db client in your machine? Also mention sql server version.

Comment: yep smmms is fine am can connect fine

Comment: Can you check incoming connections to the server are open over TCP. There are lots of settings w.r.t. Also you could try one thing, i.e try to connect using python code script. If that also fails then it's not the node mssql module after all.

Comment: Hi this has been resolved now thanks anyways!

Comment: Care to write the solution for the problem. It might help somebody else as well. Plus you'll also get upvotes :)

Comment: Have done : )  thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by creating a default instance of sql and using this instead of the named instance I was trying to use.